# Facebook sdk permissions

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, permissions

I have to auth user at my page with js (using open auth) with asking permissions for posting at wall. After that I should be able to write at user wall without confirm dialog about this. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as I know you should add "publish_stream" to the asked permissions. That's from the

> Facebook's documentation: Enables your app to post content, comments,
>   and likes to a user's stream and to the streams of the user's friends.
>   With this permission, you can publish content to a user's feed at any
>   time, without requiring offline_access. However, please note that
>   Facebook recommends a user-initiated sharing model.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/